# Trigger notification once in a loop

Tags: c#

I have a loop that is running every 10 seconds that does a few things. One thing it does is it enables a button when there is a message that I am sending to the users of the app.  I want to send a notification to the system tray when that button enables, but for obvious reasons I only want that notification triggered once when the user has an unread broadcast.

Here is the code I have:

```
private void EnableBroadcasts()
    {
        string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM db.broadcasts WHERE broadcast_active = '1'";
        int count = StoredProcedures.CountRecordsT4(query);
        StreamReader re = new StreamReader(@"C:\\Users\\" + Environment.UserName + @"\\appdata\\Local\\Cache\\broadcasts.cache");
        List<string> ReadBroadcastList = new List<string>();
        List<string> BcastID = BroadcastID();
        if (BroadcastCount != count)
        {
            string text = re.ReadToEnd();
            re.Close();
            string[] lines = text.Split('\r');
            foreach (string s in lines)
            {
                ReadBroadcastList.Add(s);
            }
            for (int t = 0; t < ReadBroadcastList.Count(); t++)
            {
                ReadBroadcastList[t] = ReadBroadcastList[t].Trim('\n');
            }
            ReadBroadcastList.Remove("");
            BroadcastCount = ReadBroadcastList.Count();

        }
        var test = BcastID.Except(ReadBroadcastList).ToList();
        int read = test.Count();
        if (count != 0)
        {
            btnWESBroadcast.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            btnWESBroadcast.Visible = false;
        }
```

The button enables once count is not zero.  I have a list of broadcast ID's that are active from the db,I also have a cache file that records what broadcast ID's that user has read.

I am looking for a solution that will have the notification only run when the button is active and there is a broadcast that the user has not read.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap your `string` broadcast in a simple type: `BroadcastMessage`. Add a `bool IsRead` flag.

Mark `IsRead = true` and the message will be ignored with the following logic.

```
// pseudo
if (button.IsEnabled && ReadBroadcastList.Any(msg => !msg.IsRead)) {
    NotifyTray();
}
```

Then you can later add a feature for the user to mark a message `Unread`.

If you intend to persist this data in the database, then both the message and flag can be stored in the `BroadcastMessage` object. When a user reads the message and the object is marked as read, update the database with the change.

**Update**: *based on clarification in comment*
Add a `bool IsNotified` flag to the `BroadcastMessage` notification and check `!msg.IsNotified` *instead* of `!msg.IsRead`.

Comment: Wouldn't that still fire the notification event every time the loop runs when there is an unread message?

Comment: Yes, that is how I understood the desired behavior from your question: "*notification only run when the button is active and there is a broadcast that the user has not read.*"

Comment: Apologies,  what I am looking for is to have the notification ONLY fire once when the button activates.